# Help identifying the group or symmetry of this equation: $1=\det A_1 + \det A_2 + ... + \det A_n$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

The following is invariant with respect to $O(n)$:

$$
1 = x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+...+x_n^2 \tag{1}
$$

What I mean by that is that I can consider that the elements are part of a vector space:

$$
v=\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\\vdots\\x_n}
$$

and that $v^T v$ is invariant with respect to the orthogonal group $O(n)$, via $v^TO^TOv=v^Tv$.

---

Likewise,  the unitary group $U(n)$ is given as

$$
1 = |c_1|^2+|c_2|^2+|c_3|^2+...+|c_n|^2 \tag{2}
$$

and the vector elements are

$$
z=\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\c_3\\\vdots\\c_n}
$$

the invariant relation is $z^*z$ with respect to $U(n)$.

---

Now my question is as follows. Suppose I have a set of matrices $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ that form a group such as $GL(R)$. Thus, their determinant is non-zero. I can construct an equation similar to (1) and (2) like this:

$$
1 = \det A_1+ \det A_2+ ... +\det A_n
$$

Likewise, I am able to consider each of element as a member of a vector space:

$$
M=\pmatrix{A_1\\A_2\\\vdots \\ A_n}
$$

where each element of $M$ is a matrix.

---

If we understand $U(n)$ as similar to $O(n)$ but with a complex 'flavour' thrown in, then my problem should also be similar to $O(n)$ but with a general linear 'flavour' thrown in. But how can I make this precise?

---

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there an operation which takes $M$ to a sum of the determinant of its element?
2. Using this operation what is the invariance group analogous to $v^TO^TOv=v^Tv$ and $z^*U^*Uz=z^*z$, which leaves the operation invariant.

Maybe $M$ needs to be a full-fledge matrix (instead of just a vector)?